# python manage.py makemigrations

Tags: database, migrate, makemigrations

I have a project and I use django.I'm trying to do my migrations for bd but I can't do them. it gives me the error django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: user_user.I also made a User class (AbstractUser) and it still doesn't work. What can I do?I mention that in settings.py I have:

```
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3','NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),}}MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

help me to create db in mi project